# How to parse triple quote strings with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I'm writting a parser for a small language that offers the same "triple quote" strings as Python. The language is simple enough to be efficiently parsed by a Finite State Machine where transitions are triggered by a bunch of regexes.

One strong constraint is that the parser has to work on a line-by-line basis, so parsing triple quoted multi-line strings, requires at least two states for the FSM (one when "entering" the triple quote string, and one when "leaving" it).

I thought that an easy solution would be to define three regex groups for each line : one for the opening `"""` pattern, one for the string characters, and one for the closing `"""` pattern. So by testing the emptiness of these 3 groups, it would be easy to trigger the correct transition

Unfortunately, I could not find a correct regex to deal with all the cases. Here is the result of my experiments:

```
text = '"""\nabc\n"abc"\n"""abc"""\nabc"""\n"""a"b"c\n"""a"b"c"""'

regex1 = r'\s*("""|")?(.*)("""|")?\s*'
regex2 = r'\s*("""|")?(.*?)("""|")?\s*'

for line in text.split('\n'):
    match = re.match(regex1, line)
    print(line, '-->', match.groups() if match else False)
```

and the result when running this code:

```
""" --> ('"""', '', None)
abc --> (None, 'abc', None)
"abc" --> ('"', 'abc"', None)
"""abc""" --> ('"""', 'abc"""', None)
abc""" --> (None, 'abc"""', None)
"""a"b"c --> ('"""', 'a"b"c', None)
"""a"b"c""" --> ('"""', 'a"b"c"""', None)
```

The middle group (.*) is too greedy and "eats" the closing delimitor. On the other hand, when using the lazy form (see `regex2`) it does not match all the string.

```
""" --> ('"""', '', None)
abc --> (None, '', None)
"abc" --> ('"', '', None)
"""abc""" --> ('"""', '', None)
abc""" --> (None, '', None)
"""a"b"c --> ('"""', '', None)
"""a"b"c""" --> ('"""', '', None)
```

So I guess I need something inbetween. Any idea would be warmly welcome...

Comment: Have you looked how the parsing works in the Python implementation?

Comment: IDK the answer to your question, but does your small language use brackets or syntactically meaningful indentation?

Comment: @mkriegert1: Yes, but I couldn't find something useful. Python's syntax is much more complex than my homebrewed language, so its parser uses a full AST (abstract syntax tree) which I don't want/need here

Comment: @user234461 : Yes it uses parenthesis, square brackets and curly braces as delimitors for different stuff. But I know exactly where quoted strings may appear in the syntax, so I can put my FSM in the "parse string" state, where no brackets should appear.

Comment: @sciroccorics uh oh. can they be nested?

Comment: @user234461: no, I don't need nesting for triple quotes, so only inner single quotes are allowed.

Comment: @sciroccorics nope that's not what I meant. Ignoring the issue of triple quotes, if your brackets can be nested, then you have a problem.

Comment: Why not get a stronger parser? How are you planning to build a multi-line token with these constraints, regardless of what your regexes look like?

Comment: @user2357112: the main reason is speed. For simple languages, using a well defined FSM with regexes is several orders of magnitudes faster than any generic recursive descent parser. In my current implementation, I can parse streamed lines faster that I get them from the network, with almost no memory footprint.

Comment: @sciroccorics: Have you actually compared timings? Your current ad-hoc parser may operate faster than you can get input, but something out of a parser generator would likely also outpace your input speed, with the benefit of being less error-prone. It might even be faster than your current code, depending on the grammar and the parser generator.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution which was really close to my first guess : simply use the lazy quantifier `(.*?)` **AND** surround the regex by `^` (start-of-line) and `$` (end-of-line):

```
regex3 = r'^\s*("""|")?(.*?)("""|")?\s*$'
```

to get the expected result:

```
""" --> ('"""', '', None)
abc --> (None, 'abc', None)
"abc" --> ('"', 'abc', '"')
"""abc""" --> ('"""', 'abc', '"""')
abc""" --> (None, 'abc', '"""')
"""a"b"c --> ('"""', 'a"b"c', None)
"""a"b"c""" --> ('"""', 'a"b"c', '"""')
```

Hope that it will help someone in the future...

Comment: What happens when multiple triple-quoted strings share a line?

Comment: Heck, you're going to have problems if *anything* shares a line with any kind of string. Also, escape sequences and multiple types of triple-quoted strings will cause issues, if you support any of that.

Comment: Also, cases where a line ends with a quote and whitespace in the middle of a triple-quoted string will silently discard the whitespace, and a line with just `"""` will always be counted as opening a triple-quoted string, even if it's actually closing one.

Comment: @user2357112 : you are right in the general case, my solution is clearly not bullet-proof; but as said in the OP, I'm dealing with a small language designed for parsing speed, so having strong syntax constraints and reducing the expressivity of triple quote strings is not a big deal. Also, don't forget that I use my regexes in a FSM, so I always know when I enter and when I leave a multi-line string, so most of the issues can be solved in other parts of the code.

Comment: You need to actually give the constraints if you want people to know what constitutes a valid answer. (If you don't care whether people know what constitutes a valid answer, you shouldn't be asking here in the first place.)

Comment: @user2357112: I guess my OP was clear enough : I only asked for a regex able to **split a single line into 3 (possibly empty) groups** (opening quote or triple quote, data, closing quote or triple quote). My answer solves that specific question. I didn't ask for a full solution dealing with arbitrary multi-line strings, as other aspects of most complex cases are already managed by my current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This might be of use to you

```
^(\"([^\"\n\\]|\\[abfnrtv?\"'\\0-7]|\\x[0-9a-fA-F])*\"|'([^'\n\\]|\\[abfnrtv?\"'\\0-7]|\\x[0-9a-fA-F])*'|\"\"\"((?!\"\"\")[^\\]|\\[abfnrtv?\"'\\0-7]|\\x[0-9a-fA-F])*\"\"\")$
```

It's something that I cut-n-pasted from a project.  See it in action at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/aGoSsg/3).